# R - Parallel Processing and ldply error

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plyr, parallel.foreach, httr

I am trying to use the below code to make API calls in a parallel process to speed up the API calls. (I know this isn't the best way to speed up API calls but it works)

It only fails when I try to use parallel, otherwise it works. In the ldply function I am getting the below error:

Error in do.ply(i) : 
task 1 failed - "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"
In addition:

Warning messages:

1: : ... may be used in an incorrect context: ‘.fun(piece, ...)’

2: : ... may be used in an incorrect context: ‘.fun(piece, ...)’

any help would be appreciated!

```
One <- 26    

cl<-makeCluster(4) 
registerDoSNOW(cl)

func.time <- Sys.time()

## API CALL ONE FOR "kline" 
url <- "https://api.binance.com"
path <- paste("/api/v1/klines?symbol=",pairs[1],"&interval=1m&limit=1", sep = "")

raw.results <- GET(url = url, path = path)

text_content <- content(raw.results, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")


kline <- data.frame(text_content %>% fromJSON())
kline$symbol <- pairs[1]



## API FUNCTION TO BE APPLIED FOR REST
loopfunction <- function(i){
  url <- "https://api.binance.com"
  path <- paste("/api/v1/klines?symbol=",pairs[i],"&interval=1m&limit=1", sep = "")

  raw.results <- GET(url = url, path = path)

  text_content <- content(raw.results, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")

  kline_temp <- data.frame(text_content %>% fromJSON())
  kline_temp$symbol <- pairs[i]
  kline <- rbind(kline,kline_temp)

  return(kline)
}

## DPLY PARALLEL FUNCTION
kline2 <- data.frame(ldply(2:(One - 1), .fun =  loopfunction, .parallel = T, .paropts = c("httr", "jsonlite", "dplyr"))) ##"ONE" is a list varriable created earlier
stopCluster(cl)


func.end.time <- Sys.time()
```

func.tot.time <- func.end.time - func.time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't fully reproducible, so the following is an educated guess.

Your `loopfunction()` references an object called `pairs`. It seems from your script that a variable called `pairs` is defined somewhere in your local environment. However, when `loopfunction()` is passed to `ldply()`, it no longer has access to that variable (ordinarily, it would, but parallelization requires fresh R environments to be created). Having failed to find an object called `pairs` in the environment, R continues searching, and finds a match in `stats::pairs()`. This is a plotting function, not a subsettable object like a vector or data frame. Hence the error message, "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".

I'm not especially familiar with how `ldply` implements parallel processing, but you could probably modify your function definition like this:

```
loopfunction <- function(i, pairs) {
   ...[body of function]...
}
```

And pass `pairs` as an extra parameter in your `ldply` call:

```
kline2 <- data.frame(ldply(2:(One - 1), .fun =  loopfunction, pairs = pairs, .parallel = T, .paropts = list(.packages = c("httr", "jsonlite", "dplyr"))))
```

Comment: sounds like it could be it. I didn't attach the whole code because its very long but the "pairs" object is created earlier in the code. How can I pass it to the parallel run?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide a suggestion on how to do this

Comment: Step in the right direction but for some reason now I get:  task 1 failed - "could not find function "GET" . I guess .paropts = c("httr", "jsonlite", "dplyr") isnt actually importing the "httr" library

Comment: I think you actually want `.paropts = list(.packages = c("httr", "jsonlite", "dplyr"))`.

Comment: Thanks! I also had to import the klines object but now it seems to have worked! I still get a warning of 1: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context: ‘.fun(piece, ...)’ but by just spot checking the data.frame created it seems correct anyways